# Is it possible to get 2 IDENTICAL facebook's access tokens for DIFFERENT users?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token

As in title. **Can I rely on that access tokens are unique for each user?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes of course. How else would Facebook know which user the access token is for.